# what is the differences among list() and c() in R, and how to pass list elements in a function

Tags: r, list, function, parameters

I have multiples data.frames, like:

```
DF1[1:3, ]

                                          Category Subcategory                Subsystem                                                                     Role NameDF1
1 Cofactors, Vitamins, Prosthetic Groups, Pigments      Biotin Biotin synthesis cluster           Competence protein F homolog, phosphoribosyltransferase domain          1
2 Cofactors, Vitamins, Prosthetic Groups, Pigments      Biotin Biotin synthesis cluster                                                  Biotin operon repressor          1
3 Cofactors, Vitamins, Prosthetic Groups, Pigments      Biotin Biotin synthesis cluster Adenosylmethionine-8-amino-7-oxononanoate aminotransferase (EC 2.6.1.62)          1


DF2[1:3, ]
                                          Category Subcategory                Subsystem                                                                     Role NameDF2
1 Cofactors, Vitamins, Prosthetic Groups, Pigments      Biotin Biotin synthesis cluster           Competence protein F homolog, phosphoribosyltransferase domain          1
2 Cofactors, Vitamins, Prosthetic Groups, Pigments      Biotin Biotin synthesis cluster                                                  Biotin operon repressor          1
3 Cofactors, Vitamins, Prosthetic Groups, Pigments      Biotin Biotin synthesis cluster Adenosylmethionine-8-amino-7-oxononanoate aminotransferase (EC 2.6.1.62)          1

DF3[1:3, ]
                                          Category Subcategory                Subsystem                                                                     Role NameDF3
1 Cofactors, Vitamins, Prosthetic Groups, Pigments      Biotin Biotin synthesis cluster           Competence protein F homolog, phosphoribosyltransferase domain          1
2 Cofactors, Vitamins, Prosthetic Groups, Pigments      Biotin Biotin synthesis cluster                                                  Biotin operon repressor          1
3 Cofactors, Vitamins, Prosthetic Groups, Pigments      Biotin Biotin synthesis cluster Adenosylmethionine-8-amino-7-oxononanoate aminotransferase (EC 2.6.1.62)          1
```

So, when I tied to make a single data.frame, I usually do:

```
myDF <- list(DF1, DF2, DF3) %>% purrr::reduce(full_join, by =c("Category", "Subcategory", "Subsystem", "Role"))
```

and the result is

```
myDF[1:3, 1:7]

                                          Category Subcategory                Subsystem                                                                     Role      NameDF1    NameDF2    NameDF3
1 Cofactors, Vitamins, Prosthetic Groups, Pigments      Biotin Biotin synthesis cluster           Competence protein F homolog, phosphoribosyltransferase domain          1          1          1
2 Cofactors, Vitamins, Prosthetic Groups, Pigments      Biotin Biotin synthesis cluster                                                  Biotin operon repressor          1          1          1
3 Cofactors, Vitamins, Prosthetic Groups, Pigments      Biotin Biotin synthesis cluster Adenosylmethionine-8-amino-7-oxononanoate aminotransferase (EC 2.6.1.62)          1          1          1
```

Everything is ok until here, my problem is when I try to make a function and use c() instead a list()

```
myFunction <- function(Files=NULL){
        # the function is longer, but this part is my problem !! 
        require(dplyr)
        require(purrr)
        l <- list(Files)
        myDF <- l %>% reduce(full_join, by =c("Category", "Subcategory", "Subsystem", "Role"))
        return(myDF)

    }

myFunction(Files=c(DF1, DF2, DF2))
```

it give me a list, but I want a data.frame, so I eliminate the l <- list(File) line, and use it outside of the function:

```
myFunction <- function(Files=NULL){
        require(dplyr)
        require(purrr)
        myDF <- Files %>% reduce(full_join, by =c("Category", "Subcategory", "Subsystem", "Role"))
        return(myDF)

    }
```

and then

```
l <- list(DF1, DF2, DF2)

myFunction(Files=l )
```

and it gave me the correct format:

```
myDF[1:3, ]

                                          Category Subcategory                Subsystem                                                                     Role      NameDF1    NameDF2    NameDF3
1 Cofactors, Vitamins, Prosthetic Groups, Pigments      Biotin Biotin synthesis cluster           Competence protein F homolog, phosphoribosyltransferase domain          1          1          1
2 Cofactors, Vitamins, Prosthetic Groups, Pigments      Biotin Biotin synthesis cluster                                                  Biotin operon repressor          1          1          1
3 Cofactors, Vitamins, Prosthetic Groups, Pigments      Biotin Biotin synthesis cluster Adenosylmethionine-8-amino-7-oxononanoate aminotransferase (EC 2.6.1.62)          1          1          1
```

my question is, how to add all data.frames in the parameters function using c() (how is the most common in R functions) ? and not use the list() outside of the function !!!

I want something like:

```
myFunction(Files=c(DF1,DF2,DF3,DFn))
```

I don't Want to use the list() outside of the function

```
l <- list(DF1,DF2,DF3,DFn)
myFunction(Files=l)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with just passing `list(DF1, DF2, DF3)` into your function, which is likely the best choice. If you still don't like it, you could also try the following:

```
myFunction = function(...) {
  require(dplyr)
  require(purrr)
  dfs = list(...)
  reduce(
    dfs, full_join, 
    by =c("Category", "Subcategory", "Subsystem", "Role")
  )
}

myFunction(DF1, DF2, DF3)
```

To explain the problem with your original code: When you call `reduce()` in your example, you need to pass a list of data frames, i.e. `list(DF1, DF2, DF3)`. Your problem is that `list(c(DF1, DF2, DF3))` (which is what your original function creates) and `list(DF1, DF2, DF3)` are completely different.

I recommend you run these two expressions in your console to better understand. Since a data frame is a list, `c(DF1, DF2, DF3)` creates a single list that contains each data frame's columns as elements. What you actually want is a list containing three separate lists (which are data frames).